# Implement Caching in Apache Shiro using JBoss Infinspan

Tags: java, shiro, infinispan

I am using Apache shiro in a project for security implementation. I have injected the security realm using CDI. I want to implement authentication and authorization caching in shiro using Jboss Infinispan. Can someone please share some pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement org.apache.shiro.cache.Cache and org.apache.shiro.cache.CacheManager to implement caching in shiro. If you want to use infinispan then follow these steps:

Implement org.apache.shiro.cache.Cache

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.shiro.cache.Cache;
import org.apache.shiro.cache.CacheException;


public class InfinispanCache<K, V> implements Cache<K, V> {


    private final org.infinispan.Cache<K, V> cacheProxy;

    public InfinispanCache(final org.infinispan.Cache<K, V> cacheProxy) {
        this.cacheProxy = cacheProxy;
    }


    @Override
    public V get(final K key) throws CacheException {
        return cacheProxy.get(key);
    }


    @Override
    public V put(final K key, final V value) throws CacheException {
        return cacheProxy.put(key, value);
    }


    @Override
    public V remove(final K key) throws CacheException {
        return cacheProxy.remove(key);
    }


    @Override
    public void clear() throws CacheException {
        cacheProxy.clear();
    }


    @Override
    public int size() {
        return cacheProxy.size();
    }


    @Override
    public Set<K> keys() {
        return cacheProxy.keySet();
    }


    @Override
    public Collection<V> values() {
        return cacheProxy.values();
    }

}
```

Implement org.apache.shiro.cache.CacheManager

```
import org.apache.shiro.cache.Cache;
import org.apache.shiro.cache.CacheException;
import org.apache.shiro.cache.CacheManager;
import org.infinispan.manager.CacheContainer;


public class InfinispanCacheManager implements CacheManager {


    private final CacheContainer cacheContainer;

    public InfinispanCacheManager(final CacheContainer cacheContainer) {
        this.cacheContainer = cacheContainer;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public <K, V> Cache<K, V> getCache(final String name) throws CacheException {
        return new InfinispanCache(cacheContainer.getCache(name));
    }

}
```

Inject Cache Container. It should work if your Realm is CDI enabled.

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;

 /** The security cache manager. */
    @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/infinispan/container/<YOUR CACHE CONTAINER NAME>")
    private EmbeddedCacheManager securityCacheManager;
```

Set your cache manager in your realm implementation:

```
setCachingEnabled(true);
setAuthenticationCachingEnabled(true);
setAuthorizationCachingEnabled(true);
setCacheManager(new InfinispanCacheManager(securityCacheManager));
setAuthenticationCacheName(authenticationCacheName);
setAuthorizationCacheName(authorizationCacheName);
```

Similarly, you can implement it in Shiro with other caching frameworsk.